# Call a link/URL using CURL command in PHP

Tags: php, curl, hidden, google-apps, logout

I want to logout using curl command from google apps account. I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Where have I gone wrong ?

```
$ch = curl_init("https://mail.google.com/a/MY_DOMAIN.in/?logout&hl=en" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=fdbdcaa41b2075a9f90b74cd885a932b');
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Apart from this, is there any other way I can call the above URL without showing the output to the user in PHP ? Please help ! I can furnish with any other information if you require.

Answer (score 0):

call `session_write_close()` before sending the request.

see this **[blog](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/)**

Comment: It still isn't working. When i call this code, absolutely nothing happens. And there is no way to check the status of curl request. Also, I don't know what all parameters to pass. :'(